# LlamaIndex library not respecting LLAMA_INDEX_CACHE_DIR environment variable

Tags: python, llama-index

I'm using the `LlamaIndex` library in my Python project to handle some data processing tasks. According to the documentation [(Link)](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html#quickstart-installation-from-pip), I can control the location where additional data is downloaded by setting the `LLAMA_INDEX_CACHE_DIR` environment variable. However, despite setting this environment variable, the `LlamaIndex` library seems to ignore it and continues to store data in a different location.

Here's how I'm setting the environment variable in my Python script:

```
import os

os.environ["LLAMA_INDEX_CACHE_DIR"] = "/path/to/my/cache/directory"
```

When creating the index storage (see code below), `nltk_data` gets downloaded to `/Users/user/nltk_data` instead of the path I set in as the environment variable.

```
loader = UnstructuredReader()
doc = loader.load_data(file=Path(file), split_documents=False)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults()
cur_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(doc, storage_context=storage_context)
storage_context.persist(persist_dir=f"./storage/name")
```

I've checked for typos, ensured correct permissions on the cache directory, and set the environment variable before importing the `LlamaIndex` library, but the issue persists.

Could anyone suggest why `LlamaIndex` might not be respecting the `LLAMA_INDEX_CACHE_DIR` environment variable, and how I can troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. What worked for me was setting `TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR` instead of `LLAMA_INDEX_CACHE_DIR`.

In my case llama_index was loading some other library called tiktoken:

```
enc = tiktoken.get_encoding("gpt2")
```

And then that checks these two environment variables instead of `LLAMA_INDEX_CACHE_DIR`:

```
if "TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR" in os.environ:
    cache_dir = os.environ["TIKTOKEN_CACHE_DIR"]
elif "DATA_GYM_CACHE_DIR" in os.environ:
    cache_dir = os.environ["DATA_GYM_CACHE_DIR"]
```